# IE not recognizing website's media queries

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, media-queries

I've developed a [Rails 3 app](http://tressaweb.brianroisentul.com.ar). If you browse it using Chrome or Firefox it will be displayed using the defined media queries. But if you use IE 7 and 8, at least, you will see media queries are not being recognized (i.e.: centered header "Acceder", mobile-style menu behind Search icon, single-line products, etc.).

I've read a lot of posts, and I'm using respond.js and some other fixes, but it looks like there's something else that's causing the problem.

Could you please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: 404 - http://tressaweb.brianroisentul.com.ar/javascripts/respond.min.js

Comment: Fixed that. Thanks. But the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 7 and 8 do not properly support CSS media queries: http://caniuse.com/#search=media

I do see you note that you are using respond.js to get around this limitation.  But as @sdcr pointed out above, this file is missing from the requested path.

I also note the following error on your linked page:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
>
> bootstrap.min.js:6 (anonymous function)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I googled this and it's supposed to happen when you call bootstrap.js before jquery.js. This is not the case. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry. There was another call for that file before jquery's. Now the error is gone but the original problem persists.

Comment: Problem solved! I cleared IE's cache. Thanks so much!